# Number of ways of selecting atleast one book from 9 different books of 10 copies each.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Number of ways of selecting atleast one book from 9 different books of 10 copies each.

Let $x_i$ denote the number of copies selected from $i^{\text{th}}$ type of book.

$$\sum_{i=1}^9 x_i\le 90$$
I introduced a variable $y:0\le y\le 90$ to remove the inequality.
$$\sum_{i=1}^9 x_i+y= 90$$
So number of ways will the coefficient of $x^{90}$ in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^{10})^9(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{90})$$

But the answer given is $11^9-1$

Comment: How many books do you select in total?

Comment: @barakmanos Atleast one. I can select upto 90 books.

Comment: If you ignore the "at least one" you can choose between $0$ and $10$ of the first book, hence $11$ options, similarly $11$ options for the next...so $11^9$ altogether.  one of those corresponds to "no books at all" so remove that one...

Comment: @lulu what's the mistake in my attempt?

Comment: Nothing.  Well, your second factor should read $(1+x+x^2+\dots x^{89})$ as you don't allow $y=90$.

Comment: As a sanity check, I typed: expand (sum(x^i,i=0 to10))^9(sum(x^k, k=0 to 89)) into wolfram alpha and read off the coefficient of $x^{90}$...which turns out to be $2357947690=11^9-1$.